# How does C/C++ select work with gpio under Linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, select, gpio

How does select work with gpio under Linux?

Is it possible to use select to create a kind of interrupt driven program, 
maybe with the help of some threads?

And what shall I think about when I use the select call?

Thanks

---

Note:
I have read the man page on select, but I think I need some more help on this topic.

- man 3posix select
- man 2 select
- man 2 select_tut

---

**Update**: The gpio is exposed in the sysfs gpio block. But I don't know if I can use that with select.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with GPIO, but it seems to be something hardware related.  Are you able to obtain a file descriptor which refers to the GPIO device?  If so, you may be able to use that with `select`.  If you can't get a file descriptor (aka handle of type `int`), you can't use `select`.

Comment: Does your device expose GPIOs to userspace as file descriptors? BTW, you've missed `select_tut(2)`.

Comment: @ninjalj: Thanks for the select_tut(2), looks good must read that one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently you can use select() on a GPIO exposed through sysfs, but only if it can be configured to generate an interrupt. Your platform may have this or not.

What you want to read though is Documentation/gpio.txt in your kernel source, which mentions how to enable an interrupt for a pin if the kernel driver allows it.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to write multi-threaded program that looks for interrupts and does something when they occur.  [This blog](http://www.moythreads.com/wordpress/2009/12/22/select-system-call-limitation/) highlights what can be done when you are hitting the limitations of select.  I have not worked with GPIOs but from what I read up, GPIO should not be very different from the telephony/network card discussed in the blog mentioned above.